# socket java ayudenme

Tags: java, socket

Necesito ayuda con este socket, ¿qué se le tiene que agregar?

```
 import java.net.*; import java.io.*; public class Ejemplo1Receptor {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     if (args.length != 1)
         System.out.println
         ("Este programa requiere un argumento de linea de mandato.");
     else
     {
         int puerto = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         final int MAX_LON = 10;
        try 
        {

             DatagramSocket miSocket = new DatagramSocket(puerto);
             byte[ ] almacen = new byte[MAX_LON];
             DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(almacen, MAX_LON);
             miSocket.receive(datagram);
             String mensaje = new String(almacen);
             System.out.println(mensaje);
             miSocket.close( );

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 } }
```

este es el emisor

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*; 
public class Ejemplo1Emisor {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 3)
            System.out.println("Este programa requiere 3 argumentos de linea de mandato");
        else {
            try {
                InetAddress maquinaReceptora = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
                int puertoReceptor=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                String mensaje = args[2];

                DatagramSocket miSocket = new DatagramSocket ();
                byte[] almacen = mensaje.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(almacen, almacen.length);
                miSocket.send(datagram);
                miSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En tu emisor, en la creación del DatagramPacket, ¿no deberías de añadir la IP y puerto destino del paquete? Aqui un [ejemplo](http://nereida.deioc.ull.es/~cleon/doctorado/doc06/doc06/html/node8.html)

Comment: Que problema te da?

Comment: Cadeq gracias por los ejemplos ya entendi un poco mejor!